# Create Altair Chart of Value Counts of Multiple Columns

Tags: python, bar-chart, altair

Using Altair charting, how can I create a chart of value_counts() of multiple columns? This is easily done by matplotlib. How can the identical chart be created using Altair?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[0,1,2,3], 
               'Col2':[0,1,2,2], 
               'Col3':[2,3,3,3]}) 

pd.DataFrame({col:df[col].value_counts(normalize=True) for col in df}).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import altair as alt


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1':[0,1,2,3], 
    'Col2':[0,1,2,2], 
    'Col3':[2,3,3,3]
}).melt(var_name='column')

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='column',
    y='count()',
    column='value:O',
    color='column'
)
```

[image]

In the next major release of Altair you can [use the offset channels instead of faceting as in this example.](https://joelostblom.github.io/altair-docs/gallery/grouped_bar_chart2.html)